# Scikit-learn methods inside functions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the following function that uses a specific method of `sklearn.preprocessing`.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
def process (data):
    method = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    tranf = method.fit_transform(data)
    return tranf
```

What I would like to have is a function that is able to call any method from `sklearn.preprocessing`. It would look this.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
def process (data, whichmethod):
    method = preprocessing.whichmethod()
    tranf = method.fit_transform(data)
    return tranf
```

Please educate me on python and apologies, since I do get the feeling that this is  super simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is much easier to pass the correct object already, instead of the name in `preprocessing`:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
def process (data, method):
    tranf = method.fit_transform(data)
    return tranf
process(data, preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()) # how you would reproduce your first example
```

Comment: This code will give an error because you have not constructed the object. You are just passing the class.

Comment: What do you mean by `the object`? Do you mean the `data` that is used to call `process(data, ...`?

Comment: `method` variable. You pass `preprocessing.MinMaxScaler` which is a class. You cannot use `preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.fit_transform()`. Either you have to instantiate the object by calling `method()` [Observe the brackets], or you need to send the object already by doing `process(data, preprocessing.MinMaxScaler())`  [Again observe the brackets after MinMaxScaler].

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the limitation of calling a function() by using arguments.

Solution that I can offer as below, by adding if statement; not an efficient one but serves your needs:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
def process (data, whichmethod):
    If lower(whichmethod) == lower(StandardScaler):
        method = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
    If lower(whichmethod) == lower(MinMaxScaler):
        method = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    If lower(whichmethod) == lower(QuantileTransformer):
        method = preprocessing.QuantileTransformer()
    #you can add if statement pairing with the class and functions that you want, as much as you need. Very tiring works. But worth it if we work all the time with sklearn.preprocessing
    # the only good thing about this code, you don't need to care about lower-upper case of function. Write minmaxscaler, Minmaxscaler, it will work. 

    tranf = method.fit_transform(data)
    return tranf
```

Comment: You should check your code before posting. First, Python is case-sensitive. So, it's `if` not `If`. Second the names against which you compare should be strings, i.e. enclosed with `"`'s. Third, what if no conditions evaluates to true? Your code should handle that graceously, maybe with some error message. And lastly, it would be neater to use `elif` instead of the second and third `if`.